# Extract all images from PowerPoint using COM

Tags: com, powerpoint

How do I extract all the images from a PowerPoint file programatically using COM?

Comment: just plagiarized from web: http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/visualbasic-l/export-msoshapetype-msolinkedoleobject-from-powerpoint-47712 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa201189 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa201366 PictureFormat and OLEFormat For Each ImageShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes ' do something to the shape (perhaps make sure it's an image? Next ImageShape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are two ways. One of them is for PowerPoint 2007 and 2010 only. But:

1. It's not COM - you just open the
   file as a zip and go to the /media
   folder and then you have access to
   all the images.
2. These are the raw images, not the
   images that PowerPoint renders if
   you've apply any affects to them
   (like Brightness/Contrast, Recolor,
   etc.).

The way in COM is through a depreciated feature called `Shape.Export`. In order to get access to it's Intellisense, you have to choose "Show Hidden Members" in the VBE (assuming you're using VBA for this). Here's the code for using it:

```
Sub SaveAllPictures()
    Dim ap As Presentation: Set ap = ActivePresentation
    Dim savePath As String
    savePath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\files\"
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sl As Slide
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sl In ap.Slides
        For Each sh In sl.Shapes
            If sh.Type = msoPicture Then
                sh.Export PathName:=savePath & sh.Name & CStr(i) & ".png", Filter:=ppShapeFormatPNG
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: this look great, but I can't test it !! , the Export function (sh.Export) is not supported, I am importing Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint version 15, any hint please ??